# Can you open a PayPalMe Link with the PayPal App through a NFC Sticker?

Tags: paypal, nfc

I have a NFC Sticker that opens my paypal.me link in the browser.
I asked myself if its possible to open that link with the installed app on my phone?

Currently I use the app NFC-Tools to write on the NFC tag.

Answer (score 0):

So sad that 9 months later, there is no answer.
I have almost the same question/problem.
A step further than a PayPal/me link, I have a PayPal request link for a certain amount, that :

- works just fine when scanned from the original QR code generated by Paypal
- works just fine when the link is opened by the user on his smartphone
- works absolutely not fine when it's opened (same link), from an NFC tag. This roots you in your browser to the Playstore page of PayPal app... Why !?

Original QR code :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcIii.jpg

Link extracted from QR code :
https://www.paypal.com/qrcodes/managed/303d3c62-6b60-4de6-963c-73fee5dc8710?utm_source=bizapp&amount=1.2&currency_code=EUR

Click it will open PayPal app to send me 1,20€.
Put it on NFC tag and tap it, bullshit appens...

Feel free to test them all and send money